# LifeRay: When I build the war, my changes are removed

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, liferay, war

I have setted up a liferay environament with eclipse and tomcat (first time I use any of them),

And I want to make some changes, for example, I add a `<p>` in the end of the `navigation.vm`:

[image]

But when I build the war, like this:

[image]

My change dissapears:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this may help: Try to open the XML file build-common-theme.xml under the themes folder in your SDK and remove all the preservelastmodified="true" (or set them to false).

Comment: Where exactly is this file located?

Comment: docroot/templates/navigation.vm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably you're trying to edit the `portal-normal.vm` under

> yourTheme/docroot/templates

but you can't.
You have to create a new folder called `_diffs` under

> yourTheme/docroot

in which you copy the folders structure of `docroot`, in this case you need only of `template` folder in which create a new file called `portal-normal.vm`.

And that will be the file you can edit!

for more details :
https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7

PS
Obviously you can copy the original content of `portal-normal.vm`

PPS
I really don't know why liferay does not create the `_diffs` folder as default of a theme project!

> EDIT

I forgot to say that you have to copy the folder structure of `docroot` in `_diffs`

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, thing is doing it like this, once I upload the .war into liferay, eclipse logs this http://pastebin.com/VdWTgDdK

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure , but you can try to rename you theme project and delete the 'theme' word, couse liferay append it automatically (rename project is often a big trouble, so maybe you can create a new one).

Answer (score 0):

In other words... if you don't want to see the content removed of the files *.vm (for example `portal_normal.vm`) you must first create a folder `templates` in the folder `docroot/_diffs` with the files *.vm.

When we generate the WAR file, will automatically take the changes and you will see them in the folder `docroot/templates/*.vm` and also in the WAR file.

[image]